# Android: ListView pushes out everything else below it

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

In my app, there is a tabbed activity with three `fragments`. The first fragment has a form to create a new task, the second fragment has the list of all the saved tasks, and the third fragment will show the comments on a task when selected from the list in the second fragment. The third `fragment` is also supposed to act like a chat activity which posts comments when you type them in and tap the send button. The XML layout of this third `fragment` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.ishita.assigntasks.CommentsFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/frag_task_details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#dd55ff"
    android:padding="10dp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/frag_comment_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:transcriptMode="normal" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/frag_msg_edit"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/frag_send_btn"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:contentDescription="@string/send_btn"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, there is a `TextView` and a `ListView` and below that is another `LinearLayout`. Here is how it should look (the purple bar is the `TextView`):

[image: expected_behavior]

And here is how it actually looks:

[image: malfunctioning_behavior]

The `TextView` shows up above the `ListView`, but the `LinearLayout` does not. It is there, though. If I do `android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"` on the outermost `LinearLayout`, it does show up, but the `ActionBar` scrolls up and overlaps with the notification bar so that the title on the `ActionBar` and the notifications on the notification bar are both visible simultaneously and neither is legible.

I searched a lot and this seemed a common issue, but none of the solutions helped me. Believe me, I tried everything I could find. I tried wrapping the whole thing in a `FrameLayout`, using a `RelativeLayout` in place of the outermost `LinearLayout`, using two `LinearLayout`s--one to wrap the `TextView` and the `ListView` and the other to wrap the `EditText` and the `ImageButton`, etc., but nothing was able to show the bottom `LinearLayout` below the `ListView`. I even tried to set focus on the `EditText` when the fragment launches so that the keyboard would show and I can type, but even that doesn't help.

**Note:** On the other hand, if I use the exact same layout on an `activity`, the bottom `LinearLayout` displays exactly as it should.

I am unable to find the bug. Please help!

Comment: I have posted my answer please have a look at it. do let me know if it is not working

Comment: Can you want to look like [this](https://goo.gl/sxCdJ6) ?

Comment: @pRaNaY No, my objective is to have a comments bar at the _bottom_ of the screen.

Comment: see the answer i posted. I did same in my app. try it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your toolbar pushes fragment layout down without decreasing its height. I have no idea why this happens (there are no root layout code here).

As a workaround you can set fragments layout bottom margin to `?attr/actionBarSize`

Comment: This is strange because I checked it inside fragment and your layout is good. It looks as should be. I tried 4.0 and 5.1 versions.

Comment: Hmm...I tried in JellyBean and Lollipop as well, and it doesn't work on either as a fragment in the tabbed activity. :(

Comment: Hmm... Some toolbar troubles ? It pushes layout down. Could you make bottom LinearLayout bigger (than toolbar) to check this ?

Comment: Nicely explained! But since you edited a previous answer, is there a way to delete my first comment? :P

Answer (score 0):

As you have given layout_weight 1 in listview layout, so it occupies the whole space available. In order to get rid of you have to give some static height or use layout_weight in right manner

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/frag_comment_list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="500dp"
android:transcriptMode="normal" />
```

or try like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.ishita.assigntasks.CommentsFragment">

   <TextView
   android:id="@+id/frag_task_details"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="#dd55ff"
   android:padding="10dp" />
  <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="@android:color/white">
  <ListView
android:id="@+id/frag_comment_list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:transcriptMode="normal" />
</LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@android:color/white">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/frag_msg_edit"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/frag_send_btn"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    android:contentDescription="@string/send_btn"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" />

   </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I cannot use fixed heights on any of the `Views` due to project specifications. Your second solution only has the effect of splitting the screen 50-50 between the list and the comments bar. This is definitely not what I'm trying to achieve. I want the bar at the _bottom_ of the screen.

Comment: this is not the right way as you think if the screen height is below `500dp`, how it'll get displayed??

Answer (score 0):

All,

Thank you for all your responses. I found a workaround by trial and error now and thought I should post the answer for others who face the same issue. I set `android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"` on the inner `LinearLayout` (the one wrapping the comments bar--`EditText` and `ImageButton`). Somehow, this sets the layout correctly and the fragment functions properly in both Lollipop and Jellybean OS's. I haven't tested on other OS versions.

Comment: If this is a toolbar issue you should use ?attr/actionBarSize instead of 50dp.

Comment: @AlexandrShutko Ooh! Yes, thanks! This is a _solution_, rather than my workaround. If you post it as an answer, I will accept it. :)

Comment: instead of setting `margin` try `android:layout_weight="0.7"` to `ListView` and is the right solution i guess.

Comment: @ELITE. Why 0.7 ? Layout with weight=1 and height=0 eats all FREE space. His problem is in parent layout. Its toolbar pushes all layout down without decreasing height. P.S. I changed an answer.

Comment: @AlexandrShutko Thanks. Oh, and correction: * _her_ problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean), what is `layout_weight` and how it works.

You assigned `layout_weight` to `ListView` as `1`, it means it covers whole height. just change it to `0.7` or any proportion you want (less than `1`) will solve the problem.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/frag_comment_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.7"
    android:transcriptMode="normal" />
```

Comment: I had tried all this and it hadn't worked. Not a `weight` issue. Read Alexander Shutko's answer.